# Copy and Past Transpose of a Range

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim Report As Workbook
    Dim book As Workbook: Set book = ThisWorkbook
    Dim myfilename As String
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set Report = Workbooks.Open("S:\HR Compensation\Christapher Martin\Tellurian 
    Inc Job Pricing\Job Families and Competencies - Report.xlsm")

    lRow = book.Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    book.Sheets(2).Range(Cells(8, 3), Cells(lRow, 3)).Copy
    Report.Sheets(1).Range("B2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

I'm trying to get this to work so it will copy and paste entered data without having to manually change the code every time new info is added because this will eventually load a bunch of info into a "Report" per se, so manually copy pasting data or changing the code won't be an option. I know the issue is with the lRow in the Copy line of the code, I'm just not sure what it is.

Comment: `book.Sheets(2).Range(book.Sheets(2).Cells(8, 3), book.Sheets(2).Cells(lRow, 3)).Copy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using With

- Simplified, everything starting with a **dot** ("**.**") is referring to the
  **object** in the `With` statement.
- In your version without the `With` statement, what ever starts with a
  **dot** ("**.**") should have been preceded by `book.Sheets(2)`
- Not sure if 'Tellurian Inc' is with or without the `SPACE`. Correct
  if necessary.

### The Code

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim Report As Workbook
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set Report = Workbooks.Open("S:\HR Compensation\Christapher Martin\" _
            & "Tellurian Inc Job Pricing\Job Families and Competencies " _
            & "- Report.xlsm")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(8, 3), .Cells(lRow, 3)).Copy
    End With

    Report.Sheets(1).Range("B2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

### EDIT:

- You can do the same thing with the other worksheet.
- With `.Parent` you are referring to a higher level object e.g. you want
  to save the changes and close the workbook, but you are referring to
  `Sheets(1)` now, which you cannot close, so with `.Parent` you refer to the    higher level which is the workbook (`Report`). For safety reasons I left it commented.

---

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim Report As Workbook
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set Report = Workbooks.Open("S:\HR Compensation\Christapher Martin\" _
            & "Tellurian Inc Job Pricing\Job Families and Competencies " _
            & "- Report.xlsm")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(8, 3), .Cells(lRow, 3)).Copy
    End With

    With Report.Sheets(1)
        .Range("B2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        '.Parent.Close True ' Save changes and close workbook.
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: This is so much better than what I had! Thank you!

Comment: @Christapher Martin: I've added some more info. Hope you like it.